# What is wrong in my spark code to count employees of each organization?

Tags: apache-spark

I am doing some basic handson in spark-scala

The requirement is to display number of employees in each organization.

I have achieved the same requirement by using groupByKey and then Mapvalues and also I have achieved the same requirement by creating a keyValueRDD as Array((CTS,1) (CTS,1), (TCS,1)) and then applied reduceByKey((x,y) => x+y) on it . Both produced correct expected result.

Now I am trying the below style of logic. I want to use reduceByKey ,but i dont want to have a KeyValueRDD with hardcoded value as 1 to achieve the count of employees.

Please help me on changing this below code to get the expected output . Also i would like to know why i am getting wrong output here in my code

As reduceByKey is commutative i get  different output .

```
scala> myList
res34: List[String] = List(100|Surender|CTS|CHN, 101|Raja|CTS|CHN, 102|Kumar|TCS|BNG)

scala> val listRDD = sc.parallelize(myList)
listRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ParallelCollectionRDD[18] at parallelize at <console>:23

scala> val mapRDD = listRDD.map(elem => elem.split("\\|"))
mapRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]] = MapPartitionsRDD[19] at map at <console>:25

scala> val keyValueRDD = mapRDD.map(elem => (elem(2),elem(0).toInt))
keyValueRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = MapPartitionsRDD[21] at map at <console>:27

scala> val resultRDD = keyValueRDD.reduceByKey((x,y) => { var incr = 0 ; incr+1 } )
resultRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = ShuffledRDD[23] at reduceByKey at <console>:29

scala> resultRDD.collect
res36: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((TCS,102), (CTS,1)
```

Expected Output :

```
Array((TCS,1), (CTS,2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the question explicitly states It doesn't want to map over hardcoded value of 1 that is absolutely the right way to go as shown below.

```
scala> keyValueRDD.map({case (x,y) => x -> 1 }).reduceByKey(_ + _).collect()
res46: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((TCS,1), (CTS,2))
```

If you understand how spark works you are never supposed to write imperative code such as this `{ var incr = 0 ; incr+1 }` where a function lambda is expected.

reduceByKey is supposed to take two arguments of an accumulator and the current value being reduced and it must return the new value of the accumulator. In your code you always return 1 since incr variable is instantiated to 0 for every value being reduced. hence the accumulator value always remains as 1. This explains why the CTS has the value of 1 in your flawed result.

For TCS since spark sees that the key TCS has only a single record, it doesnt need to reduce it any further and hence returns its original value.